# Where can I find information about post-WW2 airports in Saudi Arabia?

Tags: airport, aviation-history

Where can I find historical information about airports in Saudi Arabia since 1945?

I am in the middle of a research project about airports in KSA (Kingdom of Saudi Arabia) since 1945, especially the period from 1945 to 2008. Any information, books, documents or images will be helpful.

Comment: @mins civilian, airlines airports, international airports

Comment: This is how people do "research" these days?

Comment: @FreeMan Why not? We don't know what other sources the OP has already consulted or will consult. Asking a community of experts for pointers seems like a good way to find sources and areas of information that you might otherwise have missed. And I would guess that "these days" a lot of research happens on the internet :)

Comment: @Pondlife from [how to ask](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) "Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs.", so it's expected that the asker share what he's found so far. And, maybe I'm just "old", but being "in the middle of a research project" indicates that one should be doing the searching himself, not asking others where to look. Yes, "the internet" is a place to look but just saying "gimme the infos" isn't research in my book. (Father was a PhD, did _lots_ of research) `</grumpy old man>` ;)

Comment: Ressource location is off topic as described in the [help center](/help/on-topic). You'd better ask directly for an information hoping answers provides references and links for further readings

Answer (score 1):

There have always been three primary airports, representing the commercial hubs of Saudi Arabia:

1. Dhahran International Airport / Dammam - King Fahad International Airport

This was a dual use, single runway airfield which was the primary international commercial airport for the Eastern province, until the new Dammam International was commissioned and opened for the first flight in November 1999; Dhahran has since been reverted back to military use and is still actively being used today.

2. Riyadh Airport / King Khalid International

As with Dhahran - Riyadh Airport is a military dual-use airport until the dedicated King Khalid was opened in 1982, and the old Riyadh airport (OERY) was reverted back to military use.

3. Jeddah Airport / King Abdulaziz International

This is busiest airport in the kingdom, also one of the largest terminal buildings in the world. It is also the hub of the state carrier Saudia. It opened for service in 1981.

There then the secondary airports which also service international flights:

1. Medina / Prince Mohammad Bin Abdulaziz International (OEMA) - Opened in 1950; new terminal opened in 2015.
2. Taif International - Opened in 1976, it gained importance as it is the closest airport to Makkah (the Holy City) - and it is one of the most popular summer destinations in Saudi Arabia.

There are a lot more regional and domestic airports is Saudi Arabia. You can find information on those from the [General Authority for Civil Aviation (GACA)](https://gaca.gov.sa/web/en-gb/page/home) website.

Saudia (the flag carrier) has great information dating back to 1945 available on their [website](http://www.saudiairlines.com/portal/site/saudiairlines/menuitem.d9a467d070ca6c65173ff63dc8f034a0/?vgnextoid=582a8a09951c4110VgnVCM10000015e25558RCRD).

[*King Abdulaziz: His Plane and His Pilot*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1615840826) is a great book that covers the history of Saudi aviation.